# Alternative to PowerBI FILTER() function in Tableau calculated field

Tags: filter, powerbi, tableau-api, calculated-field

I am trying to recreate the following calculation from PowerBI in Tableau but I am not sure how to achieve what FILTER() function does.

```
(CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Amount]),FILTER(Data,Data[Paid]="True"))/SUM(Data[Amount]) + 
CALCULATE(COUNT(Data[Document ID]),FILTER(Data,Data[Paid]="True"))/COUNT(Data[Document ID]))/2
```

My assumption was to use IF or CASE but then I couldn't figure out how to divide by number of all documents, regardless of their payment status.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need the following:

```
SUM(IF [paid] = "True" then [Amount] end)/SUM([Amount])
+
COUNT(IF [paid] = "True" then [Document ID] end)/COUNT([Document ID])/2
```

The filter is specified using the if statement.